# Catching jPlayer full screen event

Tags: jplayer

I'm trying to catch jPlayer full screen event using the following code:

```
mainPlayer.bind($.jPlayer.event.resize, function(event) {
    alert("size changed");
});
```

But the event isn't fired neither when I press full screen button nor when I press ESC to exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **mainPlayer** variable and make sure it references the jQuery jPlayer object. For troubleshooting, try:

```
$('#yourJPlayerID').bind($.jPlayer.event.resize, function(event) {
    alert("size changed");
});
```